# Problema en reactJS al conectarme a fireStore. Error: Invalid document reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

estoy teniendo un problema al intentar conectarme y recibir la data de una base de datos alojada en firestore en react. Constantemente me tira el error:

> Document references must have an even number of segments, but products has 1.

Desconozco el motivo ya que mi getData considero que tiene el codigo correcto, el cual es:

```
import { adaptProductsData } from "../adapters/adapter";
import { getDocs, collection, query, where, doc, getDoc,addDoc ,documentId, orderBy, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"
import db from "./firebase/firebaseConfig";


export const fetchProducts = async () => {
   try {
       const docRef = doc(db, 'products');
       const response = await getDoc(docRef);
       const productAdapted = adaptProductsData(response);
       return productAdapted;

   } catch (error) {
       console.error(error);
   }
};
```

Ademas mi adapter funciona de la siguiente manera:

```
export const adaptProductsData = (doc) => {
    
    const { id, category, items } = doc.data();
    
    const itemsAdapter = items.map(item => ({
        idProduct: item.idProduct,
        nameProduct: item.nameProduct,
        price: item.price,
        quantity: item.quantity,
        img: item.img,
        description: item.description
      }));
      
      

    const dataAdapted = { 
        id: doc.id, 
        category: doc.category,
        items: itemsAdapter
    }
    console.log("data adaptada" ,dataAdapted);
    return dataAdapted

}
```

Que puede estar sucediendo? no encuentro la manera de solucionarlo.
Muchas gracias

edit:
Me falto agregar mi firebaseConfig.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_apiKey,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_authDomain,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_projectId,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_storageBucket,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_messagingSenderId,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_appId
};

// Initialize Firebase
console.log("estoy iniciando mi firebase con el objeto:", firebaseConfig)

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore(app);

export default db;
```

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro, en el root de firebase encontrarás colecciones, no documentos o sea esto: `const docRef = doc(db, 'products');` debe obtenerte una colección, si quieres algún documento de esa colección, debes indicar cuál es. Supongamos que quieres el documento `1`, lo puedes poner así: `const docRef = doc(db, 'products/1');` o el documento `agustin`, lo pones así: `const docRef = doc(db, 'products/agustin');`

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias. Si quiero obtener todo los documentos podria utliizar el "products/*" ?? ya que al tratarse de una base de datos, tengo varios documentos.
Por otro lado ahora el error muto a lo siguiente:
Failed to get document because the client is offline.

Comment: Lee [Modelo de datos de Cloud Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model?hl=es-419) y analiza los ejemplos allí según el lenguaje en que estés trabajando.

Comment: *¿Si quiero obtener todo los documentos podria utliizar el `products/*`?* Eso no es una buena idea. Firebase computa cada documento leído, si tienes miles o millones de documentos en esa colección te los va a computar todos. En una App con mucha concurrencia te puedes llevar un susto en la facturación si programas mal la lectura de datos, [aquí un ejemplo, recibieron una factura de 30,000 dólares en 72 horas](https://hackernoon.com/how-we-spent-30k-usd-in-firebase-in-less-than-72-hours-307490bd24d) por un código mal programado. Firebase quema si no sabes lo que estás haciendo.

Comment: Genial gracias por la informacion. Estoy terminando un curso que al final agregaron la idea de conectarse a firebase y la verdad que me estoy volviendo loco con su implementacion.
Ahora me brinda ese error de conexión que no comprendo el porque.

Comment: ¿Qué error de conexión? Firebase está bien documentado, y en español. Te aconsejo que leas detenidamente la documentación en cada etapa, te ayudará mucho a comprender algo que es relativamente nuevo. También es importante comprender que Firebase es No SQL, por lo que algunas veces tendrás que diseñar el modelo de datos de manera distinta, para poder consultar a Firebase sin consumir grandes recursos. Hay un par de artículos muy buenos al respecto, pero están todos en inglés.

Comment: Hola, resulta que tenia una extension instalada que permitia el uso de Cors, esto hacia conflicto constantemente con la conexion a la base de datos de firestore. Se pudo solucionar refactorizando el codigo tambien.